# Unable to start container for blueprint bundle exception after Karaf restarting

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I'm using Karaf 4.2.16. When I start Karaf for the first time, I have no issues and all works fine. If I restart Karaf and try to run for the second time, I got the following exception after Grace Period passed (10 mins):

```
2023-08-10T05:38:55,140 | ERROR | Blueprint Extender: 3 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 212 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.10.3 | Unable to start container for blueprint bundle com.my_app.access.auth.cdo/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=com.my_app.common.util.ICdoSessionFactory)]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:393) [bundleFile:1.10.3]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:45) [bundleFile:1.10.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_382]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_382]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_382]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_382]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_382]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_382]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_382]
```

To fix that, I need to remove data directory; however, it doesn't look like the right solution.

A weird thing here is that the failed bundles are still in Active state and the application seems to work fine.

```
karaf@root()> list -l | grep access.auth.cdo
45 │ Active   │ 100 │ 4.0.0.SNAPSHOT            │ mvn:com.my_app.access/com.my_app.access.auth.cdo/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
karaf@root()> list -l | grep common.util
61 │ Active   │  60 │ 4.0.0.SNAPSHOT            │ mvn:com.my_app.common/com.my_app.common.util/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When a bundle is waiting for a dependency the status of the bundle is `grace period` and after a while if the dependency is not resolved and the bundle reach the timeout, the bundle will trigger a timeout exception.

My recommendation is isolate your application with minimal dependencies and start your `Karaf` instance in debug mode and put some break points to try figure out the root cause, there is no a silver bullet for this case.

For example in my project I have some bundles waiting for DB/datasource dependencies, so if my DB is down or the credentials or wrong then my some bundles never will be resolved properly and I will get the timeout exception in the `Karaf.log`

if you can share a minimal reproducible example I can give a look.

Comment: Jgarnica thanks for your reply. It's hardly possible to provide an example you are talking about as Karaf is a part of our Linux distribution and depends on some other things, also I have about 30 features with about 400 bundles in total. Anyway, I think you idea to isolate failed bundles is a good option for me; however, it's still unclear why there is no any issues while I'm starting Karaf for the first time and problems happen after restarting. I'll update the topic as soon as I find the problem.